# webkit geolocation with high accuracy using only the GPS radio

Tags: javascript, android, webkit, geolocation, gps

Hey guys I'm running into a situation where I'm needing to get forms autopopulated with location data and when the phone or tablet is using ONLY the GPS for the location data, I can't get any sort of anything out of it. When using "wireless networks" it works on my 2.4 phone, 3.2 tab, and 4.0 tab. Without those others enabled, I'm up the creek and too weak in my android knowledge to know where to troubleshoot.

Please advise and thanks in advance!

Current code is as follows:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(pos) {
        $("#latitude").val(pos.coords.latitude);
        $("#longitude").val(pos.coords.longitude);
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you just need to [enable high-accuracy locations](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position-options):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(pos) {
        $("#latitude").val(pos.coords.latitude);
        $("#longitude").val(pos.coords.longitude);
    },
    null,
    {enableHighAccuracy: true}
)
```